# How to migrate to openai 1.x.x when using AzureOpenAI, Azure search and Langchain

Tags: azure, openai-api, azure-cognitive-search, langchain

I want to migrate to the latest stable versions of openai, langchain and Azure search-documents. I am currently using

- openai==0.28.1
- azure-search-documents==11.4.0b8
- langchain==0.0.310
- 

Whenever I change one version, the others seem to throw errors, and imports fail. The reason I want to upgrade for compatibility with other packages such as Ragas and Llamaindex. I do belive that the problems may be connected to openai going to versions 1.x.x

```
from langchain.vectorstores.azuresearch import AzureSearch
from langchain.embeddings import AzureOpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.llms import AzureOpenAI

# Determine the environment (dev or prod)
env = os.getenv("ENV")
key_vault_env = ""

# Set OpenAI API configurations
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = ""
os.environ["OPENAI_API_BASE"] = "https://{...}.openai.azure.com/"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_VERSION"] = "2023-05-15"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_TYPE"] = "azure"

azure_endpoint = "https://{...}.openai.azure.com/" 


# Model config
temperature: float = 0.15
chat_deployment: str = "gpt-35-turbo"
embedding_deployment: str = "text-embedding-ada-002"


# Applying Langchain prompt templates system
chat_prompt = ...


# Updated embeddings initialization
embeddings = AzureOpenAIEmbeddings(
    deployment=embedding_deployment,
    chunk_size=1
)

# Azure vectorsearch
vector_store: AzureSearch = AzureSearch(
    azure_search_endpoint = "",
    azure_search_key = "",
    index_name = "",
    embedding_function=embeddings.embed_query,
)

vs_retriever = vector_store.as_retriever(search_type = "similarity", search_kwargs = {'k': 3})


# Updated LLM initialization
llm = AzureOpenAI(
    deployment_name=chat_deployment,
    temperature=temperature
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm in project that can run on

- Langchain 0.0.339 version
- OpenAi 1.3.4 version

Here is my set up. Hope it useful for you.

```
os.environ["OPENAI_API_TYPE"]="azure"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_VERSION"]="2023-07-01-preview"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_BASE"]="your_endpoint"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]=""# Your Azure OpenAI resource key
os.environ["OPENAI_CHAT_MODEL"]="gpt-35-turbo-16k"
```

You must also set up the truly name that create on here. You can get  "manage deployment" and create your setting.[image]

My chatbot is using "text-embedding-ada-002" for embedding and "gpt-35-turbo-16k" for model, code below here:

```
def chat_bot(model='gpt-35-turbo-16k',
             embedding_function = AzureOpenAIEmbeddings(deployment='text-embedding-ada-002',
                                                        model='text-embedding-ada-002',
                                                        openai_api_base=os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_BASE"),
                                                        openai_api_type="azure",
                                                        openai_api_key=os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY"),
                                                        chunk_size=20)):

     llm = AzureChatOpenAI(model=model,
                            deployment_name=os.getenv("OPENAI_CHAT_MODEL"),
                            temperature=0)
)
```

If model name and embedding name wrong, Azure ChatGPT will not run successfully. Hope it useful for you.